# Why do I get *No Json deserializer found for type Object* when I use getOrElse there?

Tags: json, scala

Using an existing `JsValue`, I'm parsing its values to fill out a new JSON object.

```
val json: JsValue = getJson(...)
val newJson: JsObject = Json.obj(
        "Name" -> (json \ "personName").asOpt[String].getOrElse("")
)
```

However, I get the following compile-time error on the third line:

```
No Json deserializer found for type Object.
```

Looking at `getOrElse`'s [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option), why does "Object," rather than "String," get returned in my above code?

`final def getOrElse[B >: A](default: ⇒ B): B`

I admit that I don't understand `B >: A`.

Comment: Is your first block of code in one line? Can you explain why ``json`` is assigend a ``String`` value while it is claimed to be of type ``JsValue``?

Comment: my mistake. I just updated to show that line 1 simply gets a JsValue, and then line 2-4 try to add a new field to the new JSON object by parsing the json we got on line 1.

Comment: simple workaround is to just use `.getOrElse[String]("")` even though it is a bit boiler-platey.

Comment: and `B >: A` means that the type parameter `B` should be a super type of some A. in this case it means that the default value can be more general that the boxed value.

Comment: @edofic - I'm really confused by this. Why would `.getOrElse[String]("")` fix this? The type of the inner expression is `(String,String)`, but when you wrap it with `Json.obj()` (I think that's what was meant by `Js.obj`), _then_ it throws the error. Something really screwy must be happening with implicits / type inference, but I have no idea how to go about debugging that...

Comment: @DaoWen maybe with scala's type debugger https://github.com/hubertp/prefuse-type-debugger